# Tabcontroller designer not refreshing in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I've come across this issue multiple times. The contents of the tab controller occasionally does not fresh/update. Below is an image of the built app atop the designer. The `tabPage1` does not show on the build.

[image]

I am not adding tabs programmatically. A work around this issue is to create a new tab controller and delete the old one but it's very time consuming. Is there an option I accidentally enabled?

Edit: This also goes for the contents within the tabs themselves.

Comment: The design windows shows what the `InitializeComponent()` creates. This code is typically located inside the `YourForm.Designer.cs` file.If it's not there at runtime almost everytime it's 1 of the 2 following : either the control is removed by code or the control visibility state is set to false.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I checked the contents of `InitializeComponent()` and the controller is present alongside all the controls. As for the visibility, the tab controller's `Visible` property is set to True. Am I looking at the right thing?

Comment: I figured it out. There was a column on a Datagridview within the tab with the reserved word `Name` as a column name.